# ExcelExporter.export produces an empty sheet

Tags: excel, primefaces, export-to-excel

I am trying to programmatically generate an excel sheet export from a non-empty datatable using primefaces `p:dataTable` component

after digging a little while .. I found the following code to do so:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent(":formName:dataTableName");
DataTable tableX = (DataTable) component;
exporter.export(context, 
            tableX, 
            tempFile.getName(), // I created a Temp file using File.createTempFile
            false, false, "UTF-8", 
            null, null);
context.responseComplete();
```

Can you help me finding what's wrong with this code? why the excel file is 0KB in size?

thanks alot!

Comment: do all users in server have access to modify tempFile

Comment: there are no error messages at all?

Comment: I think so, I also tried to write the file in a normal folder (not temp folder), but still I get an 0K file

Comment: @DanielMK no error messages at all

Comment: Are you using unix or windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use xls Exporter tag in primefaces.

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tablename" fileName="your filename" />
```

Comment: the exporter tag works fine.. But I want to do the export programmatically to send the file as attachment vi email.